# Turn off excel 2007 auto update external data on open?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is there a setting so when an excel file is openned that has external data it won't update automatically? 2003 would prompt the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on Office button -> `Excel Options` -> `Advanced` -> Scroll down to `General` and ensure `Ask to update automatic links` checkbox is checked.

[image]

Comment: This was always confusing to me. Does it mean update without asking, or don't ask, just update, That is the setting I would like to find.

Comment: seems like Not asking to update, means not updating

Comment: if that checkbox is checked, then Excel will ask if the links need to be updated, instead of updating them automatically. That's what @Jeff O wants. @data